# Ubuntu 22.04/20.04 doesn't boot up if 2 screens are connected

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, screen, gui

Yesterday my PC was ubuntu 20.04, it had 2 screens connected (one HDMI and one VGA) and it worked fine. This morning, however, without any change to the best of my knowledge, the boot up failed quite at the begining: Just after a warning of "cannot get freq at ep 0x86", the screen goes black and it shows nothing else.
I did many different attempts during the day and finally installed a fresh new 22.04.1 install. So with this fresh new install (and updated), if I have one screen connected during boot up, it runs perfect. But if I have the 2 screens connected during boot up, it will turn the screen black after trying the bootup just as before the new install.

I would appreciate any light on how to solve this, other than booting and then manually connecting every time.

The computer has an ASUS Prime A320M-K motherboard, with AMD® Athlon 200ge with radeon vega graphics × 4

Thank you!

Comment: Try kernel 5.15.0-52 instead of the latest 53. I've found my system won't boot with 53 but I haven't tried disconnecting the second screen yet to see if that's the cause.

Comment: Dear Accod. Thank you very much for your answer.
I have been unplugging my second screen before each bootup since November. The good news is due to your comment I have retested, and now it boots up just fine.
My kernel now is 5.15.0-56-generic. Maybe the problem was in the -53 as you pointed.
Thank you anyways!!